# Getting Error while installing Enterprise search with Autospinstaller

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, autospinstaller

### Provisioning Enterprise Search...

Script halted!

> ception             : System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException:
>   You cannot call a method on a null-valued
>                         expression.
>                            at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionConte
>                         funcContext, Exception exception)
>                            at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>                         frame)
>                            at
>                         System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFra
>                         frame)
>                            at
>                         System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFra
>                         frame) rgetObject          : tegoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException llyQualifiedErrorId :
>   InvokeMethodOnNull rorDetails          : vocationInfo        :
>   System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo riptStackTrace      : at
>   CreateEnterpriseSearchServiceApp,
>                         \10.1.0.5\sp\AutoSPInstaller\AutoSPInstallerFunctions.ps1: line 4437
>                         at Setup-Services, \10.1.0.5\sp\AutoSPInstaller\AutoSPInstallerMain.ps1: line 246
>                         at , \10.1.0.5\sp\AutoSPInstaller\AutoSPInstallerMain.ps1: line 428
>                         at , : line 1 pelineIterationInfo : {} MessageDetails      :
>
> ---
>
> Automated SP2013 install script |

Started on: 12/13/2016 4:17:59 AM |

Aborted:    12/13/2016 4:22:54 AM |

---

ess any key to exit...

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: It is giving an exception while installing Provisioning Enterprise Search.. in Auto Spinstaller

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether there is at least one web application configuration in your XML that has the "Portal" type. I got the same error because there wasn't one, changing that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you forget to include the Password for the Search Account in the configuration of the Search Application Service!

Answer (score 0):

Took the cue from Jasper's answer above and corrected the error by replacing Team with Portal[image] for the Portal web app Type.

I'd changed the order of the Portal web app creation and for some reason it did not take 'Type' as Portal. Thank you Jasper.